# Mongo possible data corruption returning secondary to replica set

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to understand the source of some data corruption that occurred around the same time a secondary was returned to a replica set.

We have a production replica set with 4 nodes - 3 data carrying nodes and an arbiter.

I took a secondary (call it `X`) out of the production replica set and used it to seed a new test replica set for some performance benchmarking. After seeding the new replica set, I put `X` back into the production replica set. Within about 10 hours we had complaints from customers that they had lost around 2 days of data. `X` had been out of production for 2 days as well. So we are wondering if re-introducing `X` caused some data reversion.

The timings line up very closely and we haven't been able to find any plausible alternative theory - hence this post.

The odd thing is that only *some* mongo collections were "reverted". Our database seems to be a mix of the primary and `X`.

---

In more detail this is what I did:

- ran `rs.remove(X)`
- removed all replica set info from its `mongod.conf`
- restarted `X`
- connected to the `local` database and ran `db.dropDatabase()` to clean out the production replica set info
- reinstated replica info in `mongod.conf` but with a new replica set name
- restarted `X`
- brought up 3 empty mmapv1 nodes and an arbiter and connected them to `X` in the new replica set
- let them replicate for about 48 hours
- ran `rs.stepDown()` and `rs.remove(X)`
- removed all replica set info from its `mongod.conf`
- like above, connected and dropped the `local` database
- reinstated replica info in `mongod.conf` but with the production replica set name
- used `rs.add(X)` to add `X` back into the production replica set

To clarify - no new data was added to `X` when it was the primary in the test replica set.

---

Here's some info which might be relevant:

All nodes are mmapv1 running mongo 3.2.7.

After `X` was removed from the production replica set, it's entry for the production primary in `/etc/hosts` accidentally got deleted. It was able to communicate directly with the other secondary and arbiter but not the primary. There were lots of heartbeat error logs.

I found these logs which seem to indicate that `X`'s data got dropped when it re-entered the production replica set:

```
2017-01-13T10:00:59.497+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] syncing from: (other secondary)
2017-01-13T10:00:59.552+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] initial sync drop all databases 
2017-01-13T10:00:59.554+0000 I STORAGE  [rsSync] dropAllDatabasesExceptLocal 3 
2017-01-13T10:00:59.588+0000 I JOURNAL  [rsSync] journalCleanup... 
2017-01-13T10:00:59.588+0000 I JOURNAL  [rsSync] removeJournalFiles
```

Prior to all this, developers had also been reporting issues that the primary was sometimes unresponsive under higher loads. These are some errors from the reactivemongo driver:

```
No primary node is available!
The primary is unavailable, is there a network problem?
not authorized for query on [db]:[collection]
```

The nodes are on aws: the primary runs on an `m3.xlarge`, the secondaries on `m3.large` and the arbiter on `m3.medium`.

About 30 hours after we got customer complaints, our replica set held an election and `X` became the primary. These are the logs:

```
2017-01-15T16:00:33.332+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] Starting an election, since we've seen no PRIMARY in the past 10000ms 
2017-01-15T16:00:33.333+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] conducting a dry run election to see if we could be elected 
2017-01-15T16:00:33.347+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] dry election run succeeded, running for election 
2017-01-15T16:00:33.370+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] election succeeded, assuming primary role in term 2 
2017-01-15T16:00:33.370+0000 I REPL     [ReplicationExecutor] transition to PRIMARY 
2017-01-15T16:00:33.502+0000 I REPL     [rsSync] transition to primary complete; database writes are now permitted
```

This happened before I realized the `/etc/hosts` file was broken on `X`.

I also found a lot of these errors in the logs when replicating one very large collection (260 million documents):

```
2017-01-13T13:01:35.576+0000 E REPL     [repl writer worker 9] update of non-mod failed: { ts: Timestamp 1484301755000|10, t: 1, h: -7625794279778931676, v: 2, op: "u", ns: ...
```

This is a different collection though to the one which got corrupted.

Comment: First note, you should not have 3+1, because votes count should be odd, not even number. So with 3 data nodes, no arbiter! To prevent that "wrong" node is selected as primary. And it looks like you have hit 3.2.7 known bug, where secondary is elected as primary, even it don't have newest data. i.e. this case it was 2 days behind primary. To prevent this happening you should change protocolVersion to 0.  cfg = rs.conf();
cfg.protocolVersion=0;
rs.reconfig(cfg);

Comment: @JJussi Thanks for the reply. But I found no evidence of an election though until long after the corrupted data appeared. When we first noticed the error, we confirmed the primary hadn't changed, then I checked the logs. I will check again though. The 4 nodes setup was temporary (long story). Thanks for pointing out that bug - it's very scary that a secondary could step up like that and corrupt data across an entire replica set. That could have really hurt our customers and us. Luckily it only broke some small collections.

Comment: @JJussi Also are you able to provide a link to the bug? Is there an issue page for it?

Comment: SERVER-23663 and SERVER-22502

Comment: Thanks @JJussi I double checked all the logs across all the nodes and there was no election. So it's back to the drawing board...